# Ionic: Avoid redirecting for button in ion-list

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

**THE SITUATION:**

In my Ionic app i am using [ion-list](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/).

Each item can swipe to reveal a button (add/remove to favorites).

Each item is a link to the item page.

The problem is that when i click the button, besides triggering the proper function it also activate the link.

**THE CODE:**

```
<ion-list can-swipe="true" class="list" ng-repeat="project in project_list">

    <ion-item class="item-content item-text-wrap" ng-click="go_to_project_page( project )">

        <h1 class="custom_h1">{{project.name}}</h1>

        <ion-option-button class="button-small button-balanced" ng-if="current_project_list_type != 'favorites'" ng-click="project_favorite_add( project.project_id )">
            Mark as favorite
        </ion-option-button>

        <ion-option-button class="button-small button-assertive" ng-if="current_project_list_type == 'favorites'" ng-click="project_favorite_remove( project.project_id )">
            Remove from favorites
        </ion-option-button>

    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

**THE QUESTION:**

There is a way to avoid redicting when clicking on the button?
If not an official way, do you know some tricks how this can be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Ionic 0.9.2 there is the directive `ion-stop-event` that does exactly what you need I suppose. It solves [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/550) issue.

To get what you want you need to alter your code like so:

```
    <ion-option-button ion-stop-event="click" class="button-small button-balanced" ng-if="current_project_list_type != 'favorites'" ng-click="project_favorite_add( project.project_id )">
        Mark as favorite
    </ion-option-button>

    <ion-option-button ion-stop-event="click" class="button-small button-assertive" ng-if="current_project_list_type == 'favorites'" ng-click="project_favorite_remove( project.project_id )">
        Remove from favorites
    </ion-option-button>
```

Comment: God bless you! I didn't know about it.

Comment: it is not documented in changelog. i only found one test and some forum entries about it. hope it works

Comment: Yes you are right, i am looking for official documentation about it and don't find anything. Anyway it works smoothly in the browser. Have to test it yet on the phone. Do you know perhaps if 'click' is valid also for the actual tap with the finger?

Answer (score 1):

In `ionic2` `3.4.0` use `$event.stopPropagation();` in (click)

```
<ion-item (click)="firstView()">
        <ion-icon name="trash" item-end (click)="secondView();$event.stopPropagation();"></ion-icon>
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <h3>{{type}}</h3>
        <p>{{description}}</p>

</ion-item>
```